# Delete Update Send Invoice

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to integrate PayPal task into my web app using the Rest API and PHP and having trouble deleting an invoice - I have been successful creating the invoice but in the sample DeleteInvoice.php it includes CreateInvoice.php - I am confused - seems to me I should only need to submit an InvoiceID to delete an Invoice - I am getting error messages that all the CreateInvoice.php elements are empty... can someone explain exactly what vars I need to send to DeleteInvoice.php ?

Comment: The REST API and SDK are still full of little issues like this, and they're still well behind the functionality of the Classic API.  I would recommend using [this PayPal SDK](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) instead, which includes all of the Invoicing calls and is functional out of the box.

Comment: Yes - I switched over to a very helpful library - angelleye/paypal-php-library !  I was able to get through my roadblocks and now confident I can complete my task thanks to your work !

Comment: Glad to hear it!  :)